# Get externally referenced class attributes to be local and inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that works and all is swell. It is coded using mostly good practises of external css files and minimal inline styles/code. All is well.

Now however, I want to send that page via HTML text only, such as in an email. So there should be no external references to external sites at all. Meaning I now must move my beautiful external references, internally.

I am thinking I can write a javascript function that finds every class of an object, removes it from that class, then gives that object inline "style" attributes equal to what the class has.

But I was wondering if anyone else has other suggestions.

The end goal is to get a wall of text, that when pasted in a non-internet connected browser with no cache or anything, will display exactly what I have on the screen of my "normal operations" page.

Comment: You don't have to remove the classes and apply `style` attributes instead. You can have inline `<style>/*...your CSS here...*/</style>` blocks in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a perl **CPAN module** for this:

[**`CSS::Inliner`**](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/CSS-Inliner/lib/CSS/Inliner.pm)

you can also find the source on github:

https://github.com/kamelkev/CSS-Inliner

Comment: Thankyou. I used this to find "Tikku" which does the same thing, but from javascript.http://www.tikku.com/css-inline-transformer-simplified